# Trying to open port 8000

Tags: networking, firewall

I have an Nvidia Jetson running Ubuntu. I am trying to set up web2py. When I use Chrome on the Jetson it displays the 'hello world' for web2py but when I use a browser from another machine on the local network it cannot connect.

On the Jetson:

```
jrraines@Georgejetson:~$ nmap localhost

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-06-23 17:59 CDT
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00032s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh

111/tcp  open  rpcbind

3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server

5900/tcp open  vnc

8000/tcp open  http-alt


Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.17 seconds
jrraines@Georgejetson:~$ 
jrraines@Georgejetson:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
[sudo] password for jrraines: 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37861         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4451/containerd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9581/vino-server    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3578/rpcbind        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3563/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4640/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9169/python3        
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5900                :::*                    LISTEN      9581/vino-server    
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      3578/rpcbind        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      4640/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:3350                :::*                    LISTEN      4632/xrdp-sesman    
tcp6       0      0 :::3389                 :::*                    LISTEN      4816/xrdp           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2947                :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           9858/chromium-brows 
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*                           9819/chromium-brows 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           3726/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           3563/systemd-resolv 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:67              0.0.0.0:*                           4404/dhcpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           5501/dhclient       
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38998           0.0.0.0:*                           4404/dhcpd          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           3578/rpcbind        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:37184           0.0.0.0:*                           3726/avahi-daemon:  
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:786             0.0.0.0:*                           3578/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                3726/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                3578/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 :::53822                :::*                                3726/avahi-daemon:  
udp6       0      0 :::786                  :::*                                3578/rpcbind        
udp6       0      0 :::5032                 :::*                                4404/dhcpd
```

On a Raspberry Pi on the network:

```
pi@rpi-HRA:~ $ sudo nmap 192.168.0.125

Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-06-24 10:48 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.125
Host is up (0.00070s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh

111/tcp  open  rpcbind

3389/tcp open  ms-wbt-server

MAC Address: 00:E0:4C:68:00:F8 (Realtek Semiconductor)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 35.14 seconds
```

As I look at this, it occurs to me that I have never been able to connect to the Jetson with VNC, either.

Comment: That seems to be a matter of configuring webpy to listen on an external interface, rather than opening the port - see for example [web2py - allow external access - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756154/web2py-allow-external-access-how)

Comment: Thanks. It took me a long time to understand but I think I've finally got it!